# How to work with a varchar field that is in a date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a table that has a bunch of records containing birthdays.
So the field is a `varchar` and each record has a format of yyyy/mm/dd (for example: 1903/11/27).

What is the best way to identify records that have a birthday between Jan 1 and 10?

My current line of thinking is to use the RIGHT functions and capture the dd and mm values into two separate columns in a new temp table. Once that's done, I'll then use "AND" to get me the records I want.

So something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * from BIRTHDAYS where (DateBday >= 1 AND DateBday < 11) and (MonthBday = 1)
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Convert to column to `DATETIME` - after all, if it's a date - why not store it in an appropriate datatype??

Comment: Will searches ever have to cross months?  This would be a problem for your current setup (I think).

Comment: Well, I'm not the DBA, so that's not an option in this case. But I did move into a temp table and then stored it in the appropriate format. I then use the DATEPART function to get just the month and day (as I didn't want the year) of the records I was looking for.

Comment: Just for anyone else's reference, once I had used the DATEPART function, I was able to use the query as outlined in the original question, i.e. query based on the exact month and day.

Datepart (T-SQL msn reference): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Birthdays
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, bDayField) BETWEEN '2011/1/1' AND '2011/1/10'
```

(I'm using `bDayField` as the name of your current `varchar` field that contains the birthdays as text).

This converts the `varchar` field to a date, which lets you use the `BETWEEN` operator.  Makes for a nice, clean `WHERE` clause, I think =)

<sub>Note: You should really use a proper `Date`, `DateTime`, or `DateTime2` datatype for this column though.  Might be easiest just to change it now - it could save you some headaches in the future.</sub>

Comment: thanks @jadarnel27. But I need to look for records regardless of the year they were born in. But yup, I do make things too complicated. Converting it seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert them to a `DateTime` type and then use `BETWEEN`.

```
 Where CONVERT(DATE, BirthDayField) BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE
```